# I want to customized my infoWindow in google map

Tags: google-maps

I want to customized my infoWindow in google map.I am not customizing this window

My live site :http://97.74.160.96/dev1/belgravecorp/home.html

Reference site : http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/live

I want to implement reference site functionality .

Pleas help me ..

Thanks

Aasim Afridi

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to remove infoWindow instance from your marker.

And add new instance class you created.

From your reference site read **google_map_functions.js** file.You will see that there is a infoWindow instance that initialize,redraws new design on map within some css classes.

Best Regards
Myra

Comment: Hello Myra ...Thanks for reply...I got the concept how should i do...But i am not implementing this concept i am getting  so confused 
Please sort my problem.
Actually i am not  taking decision where i use redraw() function in my js file.
My js file is :http://97.74.160.96/dev1/belgravecorp/js/map.js
If you can see my js file and can resolve my problem so thanks a lot..
Aasim  afridi

Comment: As I recall from the reference site code,redrawing issue is implemented on user interaction or a time interval where the code selects a marker and clicks opens the window.Since info window is your design,you should decide when or where to redraw.There is nothing i can do beyond this point.

Comment: Hello Mayra 
When i use the reference site code.
This Error is coming " infoWindow.prototype.initialize = function( map )   "

Please help me ..i am so confused

Comment: Hello Mayra Their  is no more space to describe my problem should i contact you anything resource if yes then how..i want talk to you ..your are so helpful ..Thanks